# Making an animation of Newton's Method for finding roots of a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, sympy, newtons-method

Earlier for my Calculus class, I had the idea to create a graph that would update itself to show the progression of Newton's Method for finding the roots of a function. So my question was, using Python and Sympy to handle all the messing calculus behind the issue, how was I going to graph this in an informative way.

On first glance, Sympy's latest library doesn't seem to offer any way to simply add multiple graphs onto an existing graph, which is a problem.

Hopefully someone finds the following answer of use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 2 days of work I've managed to come up with this solution however. I am still using Sympy as the backend for derivative computation and function input, but I am converting those expressions into lambda functions to generate values that I can feed into coordinates for Matplotlib. I've also cleaned up the code and added comments to the most important parts.

To use this programme (only tested on Windows) I installed the latest Anaconda package.

```
'''
Created on Aug 10, 2016

@author: Clement Hathaway

Example: enter in:

6*x**3 -73*x**2 -86*x +273
-20
-10
20
-2200
2000

GO!

'''
from numpy import linspace
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers.solveset import solveset, solveset_real

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from numpy.doc.constants import lines

def distanceFromRoot(x, values):  ## Return the lowest distance between the supplied roots
    currentDistance = abs(x-values[0])

    if len(values) > 1:  ## Only run if there is more than one root

        for value in values:
            newDist = abs(x-value)
            if newDist < currentDistance:
                currentDistance = newDist

    return currentDistance


def generateTangents(x0, real_roots, accuracy):
    if distanceFromRoot(x0, real_roots) > accuracy: ## Continue if the value we have calculated is still too far from a real root
        tangent = simplify(dy.subs(x, x0)*(x-x0)+(y.subs(x,x0))) ## Find equation of tangent at our x0
        tangent_intercept = solve(tangent, x)[0]                 ## Find tangent's x intercept

        lam_tan = lambdify(x, tangent, modules=['numpy'])        ## Function to generate y values of the tangent line
        tan_y_vals = lam_tan(x_values)                           ## Y values of the tangent line to plot

        text.set_text("Current x-estimate:  " + str(N(tangent_intercept))) ## Display estimate

        plt.plot(x_values, tan_y_vals, 'b-')                     ## Plot our new y values with a colour of blue and a ocnsistent line
        plt.draw()                                               ## Draw the plot
        plt.pause(0.5)                                             ## Pause for 1 second before drawing the next line

        generateTangents(N(tangent_intercept), real_roots, accuracy)     ## Call itself again recursively
    else: ## Do nothing
        ## Display some ending text
        print("Found value to be: " + str(x0))
        print("With real roots: " + str(real_roots))
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## Equation
    x = symbols('x')
    y = parse_expr(str(raw_input("Enter Equation: ")))
    dy = diff(y, x) ## Differentiate y in terms of x

    x0 = float(input("Enter starting value for x: "))
    roots = solveset_real(y, x) ## Find roots of y in terms of x
    roots_array = [] ## Get in terms of array
    for root in roots:
        roots_array.append(N(root))


    ## Setup Values
    x_min = int(input("Enter x-axis min: "))
    x_max = int(input("Enter x-axis max: "))

    y_min = int(input("Enter y-axis min: "))
    y_max = int(input("Enter y-axis max: "))

    res = 200

    ## Convert to use with other library
    lam_y = lambdify(x, y, modules=['numpy'])   ## Functions of our main func
    lam_dy = lambdify(x, dy, modules=['numpy']) ## Differential of our eq

    ## Calculate starting values
    x_values = linspace(x_min, x_max, res)      ## Array of x values between xmin and max seperated by res
    y_values = lam_y(x_values)                  ## Calculated y values

    ## Graph Setup
    plt.axis([x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max])      ## Setup graph axis
    plt.grid()                                  ## Enable the graph grid
    plt.ion()                                   ## Make graph interactive to add future lines

    ## Plot main Function
    y0_values = linspace(0,0, res)
    plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'g-', linewidth=2)
    plt.plot(x_values, y0_values,'k-', linewidth=2) ## Create more noticable x axis
    text = plt.text(0,5,"Current x-estimate:  " + str(x0), fontsize = 30)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)

    ## Start generating tangent lines! weo
    generateTangents(x0, roots_array, 0.0000001)

    ## Keep the graph from disappearing
    plt.ioff()
    plt.show()
```